# Proving an identity for the trace of 2 by 2 matrices in terms of a product of traces

Tags: group-theory, trace

In order to prove the $2$ to $1$ homomorphism $SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow SO^{+}(1,3)$ I was given the following trace identity for $2 \times 2$ complex matrices $M_{1},M_{2}$:

$$\text{tr}(M_{1}M_{2}) = \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(M_{1}\overline{\sigma}^{\mu})\text{tr}(\sigma_{\mu}M_{2})$$

I want to prove this identity.

where $\sigma_{\mu} = (I_{2}, \sigma_{i})$ and $\overline{\sigma_{\mu}} = (I_{2}, -\sigma_{i})$.

My first thought was to use the fact that $\overline{\sigma}^{\mu}\sigma_{\mu} = 4I_{2} $ and plugging the identity between $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}$ but I don't see where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion, just compute explicitly. The identity and the three Pauli matrices are a [complete set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#completeness_anchor) for 2×2 matrices, given arbitrary complex coefficients, so, w.l.o.g.,
$$
M\equiv m I-\vec m\cdot \vec \sigma, \leadsto \\
\text{tr}(M_{1}M_{2}) = 2 (m_1m_2+\vec m_1\cdot \vec m_2),
$$
while, in your conventions,
$$\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(M\overline{\sigma}^{\mu}) = \begin{pmatrix} m\\ \vec m \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(M {\sigma}_{\mu})\leadsto \\
\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(M_{1}\overline{\sigma}^{\mu})~\text{tr}(\sigma_{\mu}M_{2})= 2 (m_1m_2+\vec m_1\cdot \vec m_2)
 $$
as well.